# The response time is very slow if I stay connected forever when using HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I have a project related to using HttpClient (C #. NET) with WPF
I use HttpClient singleton
I made a million requests to the server, the problem is that the response time is very slow if I stay connected forever.
I have set the ConnectionLeaseTimeout for the endpoint in the ServicePointManager class to 60 seconds. However, when I used the "netstat" command to test, more than 10 endpoints were in the TIME_AWAIT state, with only one endpoint in the ESTABLISHED state.
Do you have a way to fix this?
Does the IHttpClientFactory not apply to the .NET Framework?
I am very grateful for your help

Comment: Interesting. Does Wireshark reveal any clues (it should at least help establish on which side the latency is)? What about a profiler like Concurrency Visualizer?

Comment: Anyone have any method to solve this problem? I really have no experience in programming with sockets